# Warning: mssql_execute(): message: Could not find stored procedure

Tags: php, html, sql-server, wordpress

I have wasted a day almost to solve this but not able to find solution. I am stuck in MSSQL procedure with php. i have a form of 5 fields which return a "Amount" when calculate. The Procedure is working perfectly on SQl Managemant 2008 but it display an error while execute from php code. Please help me please below my code and screenshot.

```
                <div id="middle_pane">
                <div>

                <div id="inner_pane">
                    <div id="center_pane">
                        <div id="center_inner_pane">
                            <div class="txt_content">
                <table width="385" height="200" style=" border:2px solid silver" cellpadding="6px" cellspacing="0px" align="center" border="0"> 
                <form method="POST" action="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/fedex-tariff">
                <tr> 
                <td colspan="2" style="background:#0066FF; color:#FFFFFF; fontsize:50px">Fedex Rate Card</td></tr>

                    <tr> 
                        <td>Origin</td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="origin" id="origin" onChange="">
                                <option value="pakistan">Pakistan</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr> 
                        <td>Select Origin city </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="city_id" id="city_id">
                                <option value="">--SELECT CITY--</option>
                                    <?php 
                                     $city  = "select * from branches";
                                     $city_query    = mssql_query($city);
                                     while ($row_city = mssql_fetch_array($city_query)){
                                    ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $row_city['zoneCode'];?>"> <?php echo $row_city['name']; ?></option>
                                    <?php } ?>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr> 
                        <td>Select Destination </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="country_id" id="country_id">
                                <option value="">--SELECT Destination--</option>
                                    <?php 
                                     $service= "select * from country";
                                     $service_query= mssql_query($service);
                                     while ($row_service = mssql_fetch_array($service_query)){
                                    ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $row_service['Code'];?>"> <?php echo $row_service['Name']; ?></option>
                                    <?php } ?>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td> Selection of Weight </td>
                            <td>
                                <div id="wgt">
                                    <input type="text" id="weight" name="weight" value="" placeholder="weight...." required="">
                                </div> 
                            </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Select Your Service</td>
                         <td>
                            <select name="service_id" id="service_id">
                                <option value="">--SELECT--</option>    
                                <?php
                                $service_type = "SELECT distinct ServiceTypeId from dbo.IntlZoneCountry where ServiceTypeId IN ('FedEx Cash Tariff Docs','FedEx Box','FedEx Student Package')";
                                $res_type   = mssql_query($service_type);
                                $cnt_type   = mssql_num_rows($res_type);
                                while($row_type = mssql_fetch_array($res_type)){
                                ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $row_type['ServiceTypeId'];?>"><?php echo $row_type['ServiceTypeId'];?></option>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </select>
                            </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td> <input type="submit" value="Calculate" name="submit" class="btn"></td>
                    </tr>
                </form>

                <table width="385" style=" border:2px solid silver" cellpadding="6px" cellspacing="0px" align="center" border="0"> 
                <tr>
                <td>

                <?php
                if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                {
                    $city_id        =   $_POST['city_id'];
                    $country_id     =   $_POST['country_id'];
                    $service_id     =   $_POST['service_id'];
                    $weight_id      =   $_POST['weight'];

                //This is PHP validation
                if(empty($city_id) || empty($country_id) || empty($service_id) || empty($weight_id)){
                    ?><center><?php echo "Please filled all the fields first.";?></center>
                <?php
                }
                else{
                    $tozoneCode = "Select ZoneCode from dbo.IntlZoneCountry where CountryCode= '$country_id' AND ServiceTypeId= '$service_id'";
                    $result_tozoneCode = mssql_query($tozoneCode,$conn);
                        while($row   = mssql_fetch_assoc($result_tozoneCode)){
                            $toZone = $row['ZoneCode'];
                        }
                        $result = mssql_query('set ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON ON',$conn);
                        $stmt = mssql_init('SP_UpdateCNPrice_Int_Tariff',$conn);

                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($stmt);

                    //$weight_id = '5';$city_id = '3';$toZone = 'D';$service_id = 'fedex';$gstPercent='12.2';
                    mssql_bind($stmt, '@weight', $weight_id, SQLVARCHAR);
                    mssql_bind($stmt, '@FromZone', $city_id, SQLVARCHAR);
                    mssql_bind($stmt, '@ToZone', $toZone, SQLVARCHAR);
                    mssql_bind($stmt, '@serviceType', $service_id, SQLVARCHAR);

                  //  $outVar1 = '';
                    //$outVar2 = '';

                   // mssql_bind($stmt, '@amount', $outVar1, SQLVARCHAR);
                    //mssql_bind($stmt, '@gst', $outVar2, SQLVARCHAR); 

                    //$proc_result = mssql_execute($stmt, true);

                     if ($proc_result = mssql_execute($stmt)){
                        while ($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($proc_result)){
                        echo $row["amount"];
                        }
                    }
                    die("<BR>".mssql_get_last_message());
                    //print($outVar1);
                    //print($outVar2);
                    mssql_close($conn); 


                //  $proc = mssql_init("[SP_UpdateCNPrice_Int_Tariff] '$weight_id','$city_id','$toZone','$service_id'", $conn);
                    //$result    =  mssql_execute($proc); 
                    //print_r($result);
                    /*while($row   = mssql_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    //print_r($row);
                ?>
                     </td>
                     </tr>  
                     <tr style="background:#00CFFF; color:blue;">
                        <td>
                            <center>
                                <font size="3">

                                  <?php
                                        $val = $row['amount'];
                                        $gst = $row['gst'];
                                        echo "<strong>"."Rate : "."$".""."&nbsp;".$val.$gst;
                                  ?>  
                               </font> 
                            </center>
                        </td>
                       </tr>  
                      <tr style="background:#00CFFF; color:blue;"> 
                      <td><center> All Rates are Exclusive of 16% GST + 23% fuel Charges (FSC).</center> </td>
                      </tr>
                    <?php
                    }*/
                   }
                  }
                 // mssql_close();
                 ?>
                </table>
                </div>
                </br>
                <font size="2"><center>For more details <strong><a href="http://ocs.com.pk/customer-care-2">Contact Us</a></strong> at any time.</center></font>

                <div style="float:right;"></div>
                </div>
                </div>

                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

[Rate Card Front end display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JV5Ik.png)

[MSSQL MANAGEMENT SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyTXK.png)

Comment: My first thought is to qualify the schema. I'm assuming it's `dbo` since you qualify the tables in your `Select` statements with `dbo`.

Comment: You're back again today! I assume you got the issue with the null values in the stored proc fixed from last night? Can you try specifying the login/pass as part of your connection and make sure you can run that stored procedure with the same user directly in SSMS?

Comment: Thanks for reply. yes i have double checked the username and password

Comment: i have connect SSMS with the same credentials used in script. i will share you. can you give me your email ID?

Comment: Actually, don't you need to specify the `connection string` in the `execute statement`? You are missing it here... `mssql_execute($stmt)`. Shouldn't it be, `mssql_execute($stmt, $conn)`. Maybe not, I see it in the `mssql_init()`.

Comment: Now i have changed lots of things in code and Stored procedure not found error has been finished, but when i filled the form and submit it returns "Resource id #48610840.744". i don't understand this please see my code and point out where i am doing wrong ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was just having an identical problem to this.

My PHP -> MSSQL stored procs had been working properly previously, and then, *something* changed in the environment, and all of a sudden the code stopped working.

I switched from using:

```
$proc = mssql_init('storedProceedureName', $connection );
mssql_execute($proc);
```

to using

```
mssql_query( 'EXEC storedProceedureName', $connection );
```

And all of a sudden it started working again. Not really sure why that's the case, but I'm not about to look a gift horse in the mouth.